# jetbrains Rider variable usages not showing

Tags: jetbrains-rider

I'm new to Jetbrains Rider (an old VS user). I'm using Rider EAP It used to show usages on top of variables but I think I messed up something and it stopped showing anymore. please check the image below, this is how the usages/references used to show up:

[image: issue]

This is my Rider EAP version:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So found the answer and the reason it wasn't showing is that 'Code Vision' was disabled somehow.

If you come across this issue, please go to Settings > Editor > Code Vision and check the following checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: Mine was not showing by default which should be a crime punishable by random God class refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Check File -> Power Save Mode. If checkbox checked usages not showing.